# How to get the last 16 bytes from binary file with Perl?

Tags: perl

I read an image with Perl read:

```
open (FILE,"<$filename") or die $!;
            binmode FILE;
            while (($n = read FILE, $data, 4) != 0) {
                $buf .= $data;
            }
close (FILE);
```

How can i get only the last 16 bytes from this file? Backgound is, that i want to compare the last 16 bytes from an image with the last 16 bytes from another image.

Comment: If you have perl v5.6.0 or newer, you should use lexical filehandles (which close automatically when they go out of scope) and 3-arg `open` (a maliciously named file can execute arbitrary programs when opened with 2-arg `open`), like so: `open my $file, '<', $filename or die $!`. It’s also possible for `binmode` to fail, so it’s a good idea to check its return value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) to move to position 16 bytes before file end, and then read the 16 bytes:

```
open (FILE, "<$filename") or die $!;
binmode FILE;
seek FILE, -16, 2;
read FILE, $data, 16;
close (FILE);
```

You can also use constant instead of `2`:

```
use Fcntl qw(SEEK_END);

open (FILE, "<$filename") or die $!;
binmode FILE;
seek FILE, -16, SEEK_END;
read FILE, $data, 16;
close (FILE);
```